# Exploring Mainland UK with an Isle of man visa

Tags: air-travel, visas, uk, indian-citizens, isle-of-man

I'm from India. Recently I've applied for the Isle of Man - UK visa for some official purpose. I intended to stay at london over the weekend to explore the city. I expected to receive the UK Visa as it is the one which is used throughout the United Kingdom including Isle of Man but they gave me an Isle of man Visa. Now, Can anyone tell me if I can stay in London or any other part of mainland UK (England & Scotland) with that Isle of Man Visa?

Comment: TIL there is such as a thing as an "Isle of Man visa"!

Answer (score 5):

The UK and Isle of Man form a [Common Travel Area](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/customs-travel/Enteringtheuk/arrivingatukborder/travellingtocommontravelarea/). There is no passport check between the UK and the Isle of Man. Moreover, you will always arrive in the mainland UK if you are travelling to the Isle of Man, so any visa issued should give you at least transit rights to visit the UK. Visas for the Isle of Man are issued through UK visa offices. You need an Isle of Man visa as the UK visa does not automatically give you the right to enter the Isle of Man

So in short, it's almost certain that your Isle of Man visa will give you the right to visit the UK. And in any case nobody will check your passport between IoM and the UK. Your visa will probably spell out your entitglements. If you are still in doubt, check with the office that issued the visa.

Comment: *you will always arrive in the mainland UK if you are travelling to the Isle of Man*, that's not accurate, there are seasonal ferries from Dublin (Republic of Ireland) too.  However, it is accurate to say that all public connections arrive from the Common Travel Area.